CREATING a table like using a For Each loop
I have 3 tables that I need to relate to a fourth table. I'm trying to put everything in a temporary table first for review.
The final table has 5 columns, [ID], [Name], [Email], [LocationID], [GroupID]
In this table I need to have a row for that contains a set email and name for each locationID and each GroupID. GroupID is the ID of a Group table and LocationID is the ID field of a location table.
So for instance If I have 10 locations and 5 groups I would be creating 50 rows with xName, xEmail and each location and group combination.
I was able to make the following work for one group, but I'd like to be able to do all groups with one statement.
Insert Into @tempEmails (tName, tEmail,tGroup, tLocation)
SELECT 
    'StandardGroup' AS tName,
    'Xmail@mail.com' AS tEmail,
    3 AS tGroup,
    ID AS tLocation FROM t_Locations 


(SELECT ID FROM t_Locations) is only going to work if your table t_Locations only contains one row. Presumbly what you should actually have is a FROM and then some kind of JOIN (a CROSS JOIN perhaps) between t_AlarmEmailGroup and t_Locations.

It would b much clearer if you published sample data and expected outcome as text https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

-Thom A, Thank you. It was the Cross Join that I was missing. Serves me right for studying joins on W3.

The lesson is probably don't study anything on W3.

FYI: Look into CTEs - instead of creating temp tables - it'll may your life easier.
